# How to pass array of values to shell script in command line and advice on loop

Tags: bash, shell, svn, awk

The goal is to get only the filenames from `svn log` based on the revision number. Every commit has a jira ticket number in the svn comment, so the svn revisions are got by looking for the jira ticket numbers.

The script so far works fine when I give only one jira ticket number but I need have it work when I give more than one jira ticket.

1. The issue with this script is that the output has only values from ticket-2. How can I have the output to include values from both ticket-1 and ticket-2?
2. I need some help on how to pass the ticket-1 and ticket-2 as arguments to the script rather than assign them in the script?

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

src_url=$1
target_url=$2
jira_ticket=("ticket-1 ticket-2")

for i in $jira_ticket; do
    revs=(`svn log $1 --limit 10 | grep -B 2 $i | grep "^r" | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -   f1|sort -r`)
done

for revisions in ${!revs[*]}; do
    files=(`svn log -v  $1 -r ${revs[$revisions]} | awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'`)
    for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; i++ )); do
        echo "${files[$i]} @" ${revs[$revisions]} " will be merged."
    done
done
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Because the second loop (processing `revs`) is outside the first loop (setting `revs`). Move the second loop to within the first loop to fix this problem.

## Detailed repairs

This script needs some serious fixing.

- The array `jira_ticket` was declared incorrectly - it should be `jira_ticket=("ticket-1" "ticket-2")`.
- To loop over every element in an array, use `"${array[@]}"` (the quotes are important to avoid unintended word splitting, and using `@` instead of `*` makes the expansion be split into one word per element, which is what you're after). `$array` is equivalent to `${array[0]}`.
- Same principle with looping over an array's keys: say `"${!array[@]}"` instead of `${!array[*]}`.
- Why loop over keys when you can loop over values and you don't need the keys?
- Variable assignments in a loop are not guaranteed to be propagated out of it (they *probably* are here, but odd things happen in pipelines and such).
- Did you mean to execute the second loop within the first loop, to use each copy of `revs`? (As it stands you're only processing the last copy.)
- *Please* quote all your variable expansions (`"$1"`, not `$1`).
- *Please* use modern command substitution syntax `$(command)` instead of backquotes. It's much less error-prone.
- You'll need to set `IFS` properly to properly split the command substitution results. I think you're after an IFS of `$'\n'`; ***I may be wrong***.

### Passing the tickets as arguments

Use `shift` after dealing with `$1` to get rid of `$1`, then assign everything that's left to the `jira_tickets` array.

The script, repaired as best I can:

```
#!/bin/sh
# First argument is the source URL; remaining args are ticket numbers
src_url="$1"; shift
#target_url="$2"; shift # Never used

# Handy syntax hint: `for i in "$@"; do` == `for i; do`
for ticket; do
  # Fixed below $1 to be $src_url
  revs=($(IFS=$'\n'; svn log "$src_url" --limit 10 | grep -B 2 "$ticket" | grep "^r" | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " - f1 | sort -r))

  for revision in "${revs[@]}"; do # I think you meant to loop over the values here, not the keys
    files=($(IFS=$'\n'; svn log -v "$src_url" -r "$revision"  | awk '$1~/^[AMD]$/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'))

    for file in "${files[@]}"; do # Think you wanted to loop over the values here too
      echo "$file @ $revision will be merged."
    done
  done
done
```

Comment: There's a lot of solid advice here, but using `array=($(...))` is a pretty cringe-worthy thing to leave in place. If nothing else, it would be cleaner to use `mapfile -t array < <(...)`, though that still is dangerous for processing filenames.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that there's no guarantee that `svn log` won't change in backwards-incompatible ways in the future, unless you use `svn log --xml` (and thus a tool such as XMLStarlet to parse its output).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy **`1`** I was attempting to leave the code in a somewhat recognizable (to the OP) condition, while simultaneously trying to clean it a bit (`IFS=$'\n'`). If you feel like editing in `mapfile`, please do so. **`2`** I've never used Subversion, so I don't know this stuff. Again, feel free to edit.

Comment: Cut seems okay from running the above script but i get this error: `cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try `cut --help' for more information.`

Comment: This script works but the sort is happening ascending (high ti low) but not descending (low to high) ...any help ?